# Assign separate ports for http server and publisher

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io

I'm using the following code for bidirectional communication. I would like to run the WebSocket's publisher at port 2001 and HTTP server at port 2000. Following is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)



@socketio.on('my event')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,port=2001)
```

How do I assign individual ports to both HTTP server and HTTP publisher?